# Как удалить emoji при анализе твитов

Tags: кодировка, r, twitter-api

В попытках провести анализ русскоязычного твиттера, столкнулась с тем, что никак не выходит удалить из сообщений смайлы.
Сама ошибка:

```
search("курс доллара")
  |=====                                                                     |   7%
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in tolower(sentence) : invalid input 'Когда перепутал курс доллара со штанами������������������������������������' in 'utf8towcs'
```

На месте не распознаваемых символов - смеющийся смайл.
Пробовала различные предложенные в сети решения, но все они не учитывают то, что анализируется кириллица..

Код функции:

```
function(searchterm)
{
    #extact tweets and create storage file
    list <- searchTwitter(searchterm, n=100, since = "2014-01-01")
    df <- twListToDF(list)
    df <- df[, order(names(df))]
    df$created <- strftime(df$created, '%Y-%m-%d')
    if (file.exists(paste(searchterm, '_stack.csv'))==FALSE) write.csv(df, file=paste(searchterm, '_stack.csv'), row.names=F, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
    #merge the last extraction with storage file and remove duplicates
    stack <- read.csv(file=paste(searchterm, '_stack.csv'))
    stack <- rbind(stack, df)
    stack <- subset(stack, !duplicated(stack$text))
    write.csv(stack, file=paste(searchterm, '_stack.csv'), row.names=F)
    #tweets evaluation function
    score.sentiment <- function(sentences, pos.words, neg.words, .progress='none')
    {
        require(plyr)
        require(stringr)
        scores <- laply(sentences, function(sentence, pos.words, neg.words){

            sentence=gsub('[[:punct:]]','',sentence)
            sentence=gsub('[[:cntrl:]]','',sentence) 
            sentence=gsub('\\d+','',sentence)
            sentence=gsub('[[:digit:]]','',sentence)
            sentence=gsub('@\\w+','',sentence)
            sentence=gsub('http\\w+','',sentence)
            sentence=gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", sentence)
            sentence <- tolower(sentence)
            sentence=str_split(sentence," ")
            word.list <- str_split(sentence, '\\s+')
            words <- unlist(word.list)
            pos.matches <- match(words, pos.words)
            neg.matches <- match(words, neg.words)
            pos.matches <- !is.na(pos.matches)
            neg.matches <- !is.na(neg.matches)
            score <- sum(pos.matches) - sum(neg.matches)
            return(score)
        }, pos.words, neg.words, .progress=.progress)
        scores.df <- data.frame(score=scores, text=sentences)
        return(scores.df)
    }
    pos.words <- positive
    neg.words <- negative
    Dataset <- stack
    Dataset$text <- as.factor(Dataset$text)
    scores <- score.sentiment(Dataset$text, pos.words, neg.words, .progress='text')
    write.csv(scores, file=paste(searchterm, '_scores.csv'), row.names=TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8") #save evaluation results
    #total score calculation: positive / negative / neutral
    stat <- scores
    stat$created <- stack$created
    stat$created <- as.Date(stat$created)
    stat <- mutate(stat, tweet=ifelse(stat$score > 0, 'positive', ifelse(stat$score < 0, 'negative', 'neutral')))
    by.tweet <- group_by(stat, tweet, created)
    by.tweet <- summarise(by.tweet, number=n())
    write.csv(by.tweet, file=paste(searchterm, '_opin.csv'), row.names=TRUE)
    #chart
    ggplot(by.tweet, aes(created, number)) + geom_line(aes(group=tweet, color=tweet), size=2) +
        geom_point(aes(group=tweet, color=tweet), size=4) +
        theme(text = element_text(size=18), axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1)) +
        #stat_summary(fun.y = 'sum', fun.ymin='sum', fun.ymax='sum', colour = 'yellow', size=2, geom = 'line') +
        ggtitle(searchterm)
        ggsave(file=paste(searchterm, '_plot.jpeg'))
}
```

Comment: Очевидно, проблема с кодировкой. Попробуйте перекодировать текст с помощью `iconv`. См. также: http://www.textasdata.com/2015/02/encoding-headaches-emoticons-and-rs-handling-of-utf-816/. Без образца данных и минимального воспроизводимого примера ваша простыня кода абсолютно бесполезна.